# Folders with just one MP3

Tags: mp3

I know nothing about coding, and I am hoping there is a way to accomplish my needs, any assistance is appreciated. I have thousands of folders which contain MP3's. What I want to do is find folders that only have 1 MP3. I then want to move these files to one particular folder. Does this make sense? Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I've been doing it manually, but it's very tedious...

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Comment: Answer here, just dont include the "remove item" command.>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/479789/find-folders-with-only-one-file

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, you can do this in one line in PowerShell.

To open PowerShell:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→type `powershell`→<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then paste the following code (replace path before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```powershell
(get-childitem -path "C:\path\to\folder" -directory -force -recurse).fullname | where {(get-childitem -path $_ -file -filter "*.mp3").count -eq 1}
```

Then you will be able to find folders that contains only one .mp3 file (but they may contain other files that aren't .mp3 files).

Note this answer will only work if you are using Windows, presumably you are using Windows based on its popularity and your non-geek status, if you are using other operating systems you can download PowerShell 7 which is open-source and cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my addition. You can use this method to actually move the files. You can wrap the codes in a function so you can just call the function to get the job done.

```powershell
function MovUniMp3 {
    param (
     [Parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true, Position=0)] $source,
     [Parameter(Valuefrompipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] $destination
    )

    if (!(Test-Path $destination)) {New-Item -path $destination -itemtype "directory" | Out-Null}
    $file={Get-ChildItem -path $_ -file -filter '*.mp3'}
    $folders=(Get-ChildItem -path $source -directory -force -recurse).fullname | where {$(Invoke-Command $file).count -eq 1}
    $folders | %{Move-Item -path $(Invoke-Command $file).fullname -destination $destination}
}
```

Paste the codes into a running PowerShell session, and then you can use it by typing `MovUniMp3`

Usage example:

```powershell
MoveUniMp3 "C:\Music" "C:\Dest"
```

This will move all .mp3 files contained in the subfolders with only one .mp3 file inside C:\Music directory to the destination folder located at C:\Dest.