# Find folders with no files (empty) or only with "thumbs.db"

Tags: windows-10, powershell, file-search

I recently did a photo cleanup and removed duplicates/similar using different tools. Now I'm conscious that I might have been left with empty folders, or folders with just the "thumbs.db" file in it. Is there a way to list them all so I can delete them?
Found many PS scripts to do this, but not one that looks for folders with just the mentioned file.
thanks,

Comment: do a listing of those with no files AND no dirs, delete them, do a listing of dirs with a file named `thumbs.db`, check for just that one file, if no others found, kill that dir.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the logic but don't know how to generate those lists

Comment: I just goggled "find empty folders windows" and got several answers.

Comment: See the accepted answer here, with a little tweaking you can find them, just be sure to leave out "remove item" if you do not want to delete any files>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/479789/find-folders-with-only-one-file

Comment: @elTanqueAU - try to Read The Friendly Manual. [*grin*] specifically, try using the `Get-Help` cmdlet with various words that describe what you want. then do the same with your fave search engine. ///// i'm willing to help ... but not to do this for you.

Comment: Alright, I did find ways to find empty folders. I also found that link above and run it without the "remove" before posting this question. However, I don't know the commands to tweak them to find a folder where only "thumbs.db" exist. I tried changing the count to 1 but didn't work as I expected hence why my post. I'll check that Get-Help command see if I can work it out

Comment: ok, seems I got something working
`(gci C:\PATH\To\SEARCH -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 1 } | ? {$_.GetFiles("thumbs.db") } | select FullName`

might not be the most elegant but seems to return what I'm after @Lee_Dailey

Comment: ok, on further checking, I got a result where the folder has no files other than thumbs.db, but it also has subfolders with files, so not entirely addressing my issue

Comment: @elTanqueAU - please, add the code you are running to your Question ... and add what is not working as needed.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, found a solution and added to the question above.

Comment: @elTanqueAU Don't add an answer to your question, instead add an answer with your answer as you can self-answer and that is more appropriate anyway. This way there is a clear distinction between what is the answer and what is the question for future reader. I suggest you add your answer to a new answer that you add and then [edit] to remove the answer from your question.

Comment: As to your final question (which may well be moved to your answer), `GetFiles()` returns only files, `GetFileSystemInfo()` returns files & subdirectories, so its count will only equal one when the `thumbs.db` files is present with no subdirectories.

Comment: @elTanqueAU - NEATO! [*grin*] glad to see that you got it working as needed. it aint _quite_ how i would do it ... but it works, and PoSh allows many ways to get to the desired result. ///// as others mentioned, you can add the Answer to your Question as an official Answer. please do ... that way i can upvote it.

Comment: Unless you're stuck with really old PowerShell, `(gci C:\PATH\To\SEARCH -r | ? PSIsContainer -eq $True )` is no longer necessary since the `-Directory` parameter was added (alias `-ad`) to `GetChildItem`. `(gci C:\PATH\To\SEARCH -r -ad )` returns the equvalent collection.

Answer (score 1):

I run this code:

`(gci C:\PATH\To\SEARCH -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 1 } | ? {$_.GetFiles("thumbs.db") } | select FullName`

and I get folders with the "Thumbs.db" file but also with subfolders.
So I changed the above code to this and it seems working:
`(gci C:\PATH\To\SEARCH -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}) | ? {$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count -eq 1 } | ? {$_.GetFiles("thumbs.db") } | select FullName`

changed GetFiles() for GetFileSystemInfos()
Don't understand what the difference is between them but got my answer
I'm not stuck on old Powershell, but not knowing PS or coding, I just hacked my way out to a solution.
Cheers